# Office 365 Enterprise - Word add-in Manifest Update Issues

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

We've developed a Word Add-in internally that allows users to configure some custom document properties and access some report data without going to the backstage or leaving the Word 2016 environment. These add-ins have been added to Document Templates for a number of different content types in our SharePoint 2013 environment. During testing, everything seemed to work fine; whenever you opened or created a document whose template included the App, it correctly assessed the app's flag as having it open and displayed the Task Pane app on the right side of the workspace, as expected.

The trouble came when we attempted to increment the version number, which is our standard procedure for making changes. The Manifest itself changed in only a minor way, which is to say that the target of the Support URL changed from a QA error reporting page to our actual Support URL, and the web address of the icon for the App changed, though the icon still exists in its previous location so that it didn't cause problems until the transition had been complete for all users.

The behavior we're now seeing is very peculiar. When a file containing the App is opened by a user or a new document is created after the Manifest update is pushed out via the Office 365 admin center, the app task pane still appears as expected, but the app itself is replaced with an error/warning message that says "A new version of this add-in is available. Click here to update" or something along those lines.

That's a pretty normal behavior and perfectly acceptable. However, when a user clicks the "Update" button, the task pane simply flickers as though it did a quick refresh and displays the same message, eternally. If we de-increment the version number of the Manifest, delete the exist manifest, and add the now "old version" manifest back in, the App is back to functioning - for ***some*** users. Other users see a brand new issue, specifically an error that the App could not be loaded. After a day or two and multiple restarts these issues remain.

No matter what, incrementing any value in the Manifest's version number triggers the 'update' process in Word, but this never actually resolves back into the Task Pane.

So the questions are thus:

Are there any known issues with the Office Add-in Manifest update process in Office 365 Enterprise? If so, are there any resolutions for this problem?

Does anyone have any further debugging suggestions to eliminate possible other factors?

Is there any way to manual clear the Local Word manifest cache and force it to retrieve the manifest again as though it were 'new,' as opposed to simply updated.